# How to get most recent record based on last_modified field in hibernate JPA(session implementation)

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

I've been scratching my head over the past 3 hours to find the most recent object using hibernate.i've made attempts but always returns either null, or castTypeExcetpion.

```
public Content getMostRecentByCategoryAndGenre(Category category, Genre genre){
    logger.info("calling getMostRecentByCategoryAndGenre");
    logger.debug(category);
    logger.debug(genre);

    DetachedCriteria recentDate = DetachedCriteria.forClass(this.getPersistentClass());
    recentDate.setProjection(Projections.max("lastModified"));

    Content recent = (Content)  this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(this.getPersistentClass())
            .add(Restrictions.eq("genre", genre))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("category", category))
            .setProjection(Projections.max("lastModified")) // gives cannot cast timestamp to com.bla.bla.bla.myproject

         // .add(Property.forName("lastModified").eq(recentDate)) // this if uncommented and previous line commented gives null result 
            .uniqueResult();
    logger.debug(recent);
    return recent;
}
```

is there anything i'm not doing right? thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 1):

all in one query

```
// subquery to get the most recent date for this genre and category
DetachedCriteria recentDate = DetachedCriteria.forClass(this.getPersistentClass())
    .add(Restrictions.eq("genre", genre))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("category", category))
    .setProjection(Projections.max("lastModified"));

// get the content for the most recent date, genre and category
Content recent = session.createCriteria(this.getPersistentClass())
        .add(Restrictions.eq("genre", genre))
        .add(Restrictions.eq("category", category))
        .add(Subqueries.eq("lastModified", recentDate))
        .uniqueResult<Content>();
```

Answer (score 0):

As your are using projection on `lastModified` field, in the result you get only `lastModified` value as List of size 1 having `lastModified` value in it as you get only one row as result, which cannot be cast to your `Content` class type. If you need recent `Content` object just stop adding projection on criteria.

Comment: Hey thanks and sorry for the late feedback.can you point me to other solutions please.Projection is one of the easiest i could do on my own

Comment: You could project Content ID instead of lastModified. Using that ID you can load your Content object.